# Display Map Tips in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I see that map tips in QGIS are set in the Display Panel in Layer Properties. However, I can't get the map tips to actually display on the map when I hover over a feature with the Touch zoom and pan tool. I have tried in both 2.14 and 2.18.

I'm sure that I'm missing something simple here, like, perhaps a checkbox to actually turn on the map tips? Or use another pointer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to click on the map tips button or goto `View->Map Tips` in the menus.

See the [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/) (always worth a check) for [more details](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#maptips)

Answer (score 1):

As well as enabling map tips in the menu, you also need to select the layer in the layer list, as only tips in the currently selected layer will show.  Having the layer visible is not enough, it has to be selected as well.  Only one layer can be selected at a time for tip display ([as of 2023](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/7051)).

There are also some known bugs in some versions that prevent the tips from being displayed, and some combinations between QGIS versions, Qt versions, etc. also prevent tips from appearing.

In my case, the version supplied by my OS was unable to show tips, however other people running the same version on different Linux distributions had tips appear fine (but their Qt and Python versions were different).  When I ran a version inside Docker, the tips appeared just fine.  So if you have no luck getting tips to appear, try some different versions (both of the app as well as Qt, Python, etc.)